# Set Password form - use front-end template for admin users

Tags: admin, password

I am currently building an intranet. I have created a password reset and a set password form that is used on the front-end. However, admin users get redirected to the 'Craft' set password form. is there anyway possible to make all users use the front-end set password form for consistency?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it just admins or anyone with "access to the Control Panel" permissions?

Comment: Yes for anyone with "access to the Control Panel" permissions and above.

Comment: Any ideas @bradbell?

Comment: Is this for Craft 2 or 3?

Comment: Craft 2 @BradBell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not without hacking up some core files, unfortunately.

You can see the logic Craft 2 uses to determine which set password template to render for a given request here: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop-v2/src/controllers/UsersController.php#L1702-L1720

Basically, if a user has "accessCp" permissions (which admins certainly do), then they're going to get the Control Panel set password template.

Comment: Thanks for this @BradBell. I wouldn't want to hack the core scripts so will leave it be and put up with it this way. Incidentally you asked it if was Craft 2 vs 3. Is this possible in Craft 3? If so it might be worth adding this to the answer so it is useful if I upgrade to anyone else coming to this thread...
Thanks.

Comment: Some of the user workflow logic has changed for Craft 3, but it looks like that bit is the same across both.